# Ubicación del mouse estática

Tags: java, poo, eclipse, polimorfismo

Estoy haciendo un pequeño juego 2D pero necesito disparar en la dirección en la que el mouse apunte, pero la forma que usé no me funciona porque las balas cuando llegan donde tengo el cursor se detienen y luego siguen el cursor no siguen su rumbo adjunto mi código.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Balas {

    private double x;
    private double y;
    private BufferedImage imagenBala;
    private String ruta;

    public Balas(int x, int y, String ruta) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.ruta = ruta;
        try {
            this.imagenBala = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(this.ruta));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("No se pudo cargar la imagen de la bala");
        } // try-catch

    } // Balas

    public void dibujar(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(this.imagenBala, (int) this.x, (int) this.y, this.imagenBala.getWidth(),
                this.imagenBala.getHeight(), null);

    } // Dibujar

    public void actualizar() {
        
        if(this.ubicacionPunteroY() < this.y ) {
            this.y -= 0.2;
            
        }
        if(this.x < this.ubicacionPunteroX()) {
            this.x += 0.2;
        }

    } // Actualizar
    
    public double ubicacionPunteroX() {
        double xMouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
        return xMouse;
    }
    
    public double ubicacionPunteroY() {
        double yMouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
        return yMouse;
    }
    // Getters & Setters

    public BufferedImage getImagenBala() {
        return imagenBala;
    }

    public void setImagenBala(BufferedImage imagenBala) {
        this.imagenBala = imagenBala;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    // Constructores para Bala

    

    public boolean impactarEnemigo(Enemigos enemigo) {
        if ((this.x >= enemigo.getX() && this.x <= enemigo.getX()) && this.y <= enemigo.getY()
                && this.y >= enemigo.getY() + 40)
            return true;

        return false;
    } // impactarEnemigo

} // Class Balas
```

El método actualizar es el que uso para darle dirección a las balas, es el refresh de la interfaz por decirlo así, entonces lo que hice fue obtener la X del mouse y el Y del mouse y poder usar la dirección con condicionales, pero me pasa que cuando llega al cursor se detiene y si sigo cumpliendo la condición sigue subiendo y subiendo, tampoco sale en la dirección exacta así que ocupo un método distinto para obtener la X y Y del mouse, tengo los eventos pero los tengo en otra clase y no sé como usarlo acá,e algún consejo o ayuda lo apreciaría.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías guardar tu ubicación del mouse solo una vez. En el constructor, por ejemplo.

Y luego puedes usarlo en tu codigo como lugar fijo:

```
public class Balas {

private double x;
private double y;
private BufferedImage imagenBala;
private String ruta;
private final int ubicacionPunteroX;
private final int ubicacionPunteroY;

public Balas(int x, int y, String ruta) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    // guardar una sola vez
    this.ubicacionPunteroX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
    this.ubicacionPunteroY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;

    this.ruta = ruta;
    try {
        this.imagenBala = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(this.ruta));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("No se pudo cargar la imagen de la bala");
    } // try-catch

} // Balas



public void actualizar() {
    
    if(this.ubicacionPunteroY < this.y ) {
        this.y -= 0.2;
        
    }
    if(this.x < this.ubicacionPunteroX) {
        this.x += 0.2;
    }

} // Actualizar

//...
```

} // Class Balas

Comment: gracias perfecto